# How do I insert my list item section into the header section?

Tags: html, css

My current code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Itim', cursive;
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 8px 0px 10px 40px;
}

header li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 21px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1> COMPANY NAME </h1>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#"> HOME </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> ABOUT </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> OUR TEAM </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> WORK </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> CONTACT US </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Now, the problem is that my list item goes outside the header section. I is displayed separately under the  tag but I want to display it in right side of the  in the header section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Itim', cursive;
}

header {
background-color:black;
color:white;
}
header li {
display: inline;
font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 18px;
float: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right:0px;

}
nav {
  display: inline-flex;
}
nav ul {
float: right;
}
nav ul li {
display:inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head> <title> How cool! </title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<header> 
    <nav>
        <h5> COMPANY NAME </h5>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href = "#" > HOME </a> </li>
        <li> <a href = "#" > ABOUT </a> </li>
        <li> <a href = "#" > OUR TEAM </a> </li>
        <li> <a href = "#" > WORK </a> </li>
        <li> <a href = "#" > CONTACT US </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have used `float` on the `li`, you need to [add a clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

Also, remove the fixed `height` from your header.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Itim', cursive;
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  /* remove this
  height: 50px;*/
  padding: 8px 0px 10px 40px;
}

header li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 21px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
}

nav:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1> COMPANY NAME </h1>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#"> HOME </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> ABOUT </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> OUR TEAM </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> WORK </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> CONTACT US </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

All I did was work around the CSS a bit. Let me know if this is the result you are looking for.

Cheers.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  float:left;
  font-family: 'Itim', cursive;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
}

header {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding:20px 40px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

header li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 21px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

header li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
}

header ul {
  float:left;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1> COMPANY NAME </h1>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#"> HOME </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> ABOUT </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> OUR TEAM </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> WORK </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> CONTACT US </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```